# Mostrar toast input vacio ionic 2

Tags: ionic, angularjs-2.0

Hola tengo un formulario validado, pero quiero mostrar un toast para informar al usuario que el campo esta vacío ionic 2

Comment: Considera añadir el código que llevas para poder ayudarte mejor a solucionar tu problema

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Puedes seguir este sencillo tutorial y lanzar la función cuando if(!variable):

[Toastr and Ionic 2 Tutorial](https://www.thepolyglotdeveloper.com/2016/01/show-native-toast-notifications-in-an-ionic-2-mobile-app/)

Comment: Es recomendable que añadas algo código a la respuesta para dar respaldo en caso de que la página de referencia deje de funcionar